# Flutter Firestore expand document data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple app which uses Firestore as a data source. After following tutorials from Google on how to build better database, I have started separating my objects into multiple tables (or how they call it collections) and use data references.

Let me give you a simple example. Let's say I have two collections (data tables)

- ShoppingCategories
- ShoppingItems

Logic is, that under `ShoppingItems` I can store all items regardless of category (e.g. milk, bread, poultry, wine, ...), but in my `ShoppingCategories` I create categories of products (e.g. Diary, Fruits, Meat, ...) and reference items that belong to them.

Here is how the data model would look like in Flutter:

```
class ShoppingCategory {
    DocumentReference reference;
    String title;
    List<ShoppingItem> items;
}

class ShoppingItem {
    DocumentReference reference;
    String title;
}
```

Problem I am facing now is, that if I do the following call:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('shopping_categories').snapshot()
```

I will indeed get all Shopping categories with property `items`; however it will be just of type `DocumentReference`. In order for me, to retrieve details of these ShoppingItems, I will need to do additional call to `Firestore` (for each and every sub item) and request their details.

**My question would be:**

Is there a way how to do this more efficiently? E.g. If I was using Entity Framework, I would call the `.expand()` method on my `items` collection and it would dynamically fetch all necessary details - so in one call I get all the details. Can I do something like this in Flutter - Firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Firestore has no joins by design, and neither do the client SDKs.

If you need to get all the items and the category in one operation, I would model it like this:

The {} means the document id

```
shopping_categories/{dairy}
  {name: "Dairy"}

items/{milk}
  {
    category: {
      id: "dairy",
      data: {name: "Dairy"}
    },
    name: "Milk"
  }
```

The data field in items is optional, you could do it like this too:

```
  {
    category: {
      id: "dairy",
      name: "Dairy"
    },
    name: "Milk"
  }
```

That way you can query it like this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('items').where('category.id', isEqualTo: "dairy").getDocuments();
```

And by saving everything in one document you can get both the items and the category in one operation. That's usually cheaper, especially if you are only getting one item.

That's one advantage of document DBs, you can save the document in a way that the read is more efficient because you only need to read one entity instead of several.